# C# to Require XML Documentation for internal members

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, xml-documentation, code-documentation

Visual Studio has a nice feature to spit out a bunch of compiler warnings if some of the `public` members are missing XML documentation.

I would love to have the same for `internal`, or better, any non-`private` members, but unfortunately so far I wasn't able to find how to configure the level of visibility for which to require XML documentation.

I admit that the [same question was asked a long time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172871/visual-studio-warn-on-missing-xml-documentation-for-private-and-internal-members), but the OP didn't get a single answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) to require many styling rules for your code. Xml comments is one of those rules.

Comment: You can configure StyleCop to run with VS builds but it requires StyleCop installed on all developer and build machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReSharper's [Agent Smith plugin](https://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/) to prompt you with standard in-line warnings.